# how can i retrieve 10 random documents on docpad?

Tags: docpad

I have a folder called 'clients' with 30 images inside, and i want to return from docpad 10 random images every time I load the page. is that possible? I've searched for returning random stuff with docpad and didn't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 2):

The docpad skeleton ["Kitchen Sink"](https://github.com/docpad/kitchensink.docpad) has an example of generating a random number on each page load. See the [Dynamic Content](http://docpad-kitchensink.herokuapp.com/nifty/dynamic.html) page.

The key point is to set the dynamic property in the page metadata to true (dynamic: true). You will also need to make sure you have the docpad plugin "cleanurls" installed (docpad-plugin-cleanurls) - not immediately obvious.

After that its just a matter of using the standard javascript Math.random. I'm using something like this to get a random post in my .eco file

```
<%=i = Math.floor((Math.random()*10))%>
<% document = @getCollection('posts').toJSON()[i] %>
```

Hope that helps

Edit - Jade Example

```
  - var i = Math.floor((Math.random()*10))
  - var doc = getCollection('posts').toJSON()[i]
```

The dash before the 'var' statements is important. see https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a8

Comment: and how do i write that in jade? i tried, but no luck... maybe stuff like this one are good to add to the main configuration?

Comment: Any chance of marking this as answered? Might help other people looking at this post